# Youtube API Use Eden PHP library

Tags: php, connection, youtube-api

I try ot use API Eden for YouTube.

http://www.eden-php.com/documentation/social/google/youtube

I block for the connection. I use this code like thez say :

```
session_start();

$auth = eden('google')->auth('[CLIENT_ID]', '[CLIENT_SECRET]', 'http://yourwebsite.com/auth', '[API_KEY]');

//if no code and no session
if(!isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    //redirect to login
    $login = $auth->getLoginUrl('youtube');
    header('Location: '.$login);
    exit;
}

//Code is returned back from google
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    //save it to session
    $access = $auth->getAccess($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $access['access_token'];

}
```

I have puts my dev key, id, id_secret...

But when i go on the new page and try to puts this code like that :

```
session_start();

include('eden.php');


$youtube = eden('google')->youtube($_SESSION['token'], '[DEVELOPER_KEY]');
```

Header :

```
new.php?code=4/wDGcl_A2FePVDPGE42s4p1qGH-mI.wmD1IpIt-OIVOl05ti8ZT3ZN-xDDfAI
```

I have :

```
Notice: Undefined index: token in C:\wamp\www\eden\new.php on line 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you are using seems not to have been designed using strict standard, and your PHP settings are very strict, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));` at the very top of your code to disable notice and warnings.
The issue is that the script is trying at some point to access an array with the index "index" without checking if it exists first.

Comment: Thx ! the error say i forgot to activate php_curl in Wamp. It's work now.